# custom cast function and abstracts

Tags: haxe

This code outputs `Null<_Test.Bar_Impl_>`. I wanted it to output `Foo` but I see why it does not work that way. But may be I can somehow overcome this limitation. 
My primary goal is to create function that will work like `cast`, but return null instead of throwing exception. And it should work with abstracts.

```
class Foo {
}

abstract Bar(Foo) {
}

class MyCast {
    inline static public function doCast<T>(value: Any, type: Class<T>): Null<T> {
        return Std.is(value, type) ? cast value : null;
    }
}

class Test {

    static function main() {
        $type(MyCast.doCast(null, Bar));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's indeed not easy. Would working with the generated type for Bar be enough for you? You can do `$type(MyCast.doCast(null, Bar_Impl_));` which will output `Null<_Test.Bar_Impl_>` (https://try.haxe.org/#BcdC5)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this "custom cast"?

Comment: @kLabz not sure how can it help working with generated type: https://try.haxe.org/#a7C44

Comment: @szczepanpp In our project we often have `Dynamic` values and need to do something only if they are of desired type. With such cast we can simply write something like: `var foo: Null<Foo> = MyCast.doCast(getDynamicFooLongExpression(), Foo); if(foo != null) { doSomething(); }` And without it: `var foo1: Dynamic = getDynamicFooLongExpression(); if(Std.is(foo1, Foo)) { var foo = (foo1:Foo); doSomething(); }`

Comment: @romamik You're mixing up compile-time and runtime types. `abstract` is not available at runtime but if you did `Std.is(new Bar(), Foo)` that would return `true` - because a runtime object is of `Foo` type. It'd be worth to reconsider your design - instead of checking runtime type of objects use static (compile-time) type inference with generics. To help you with that we'd have to know what exactly you're trying to do. E.g. see [Strict typing for stringly-typed extern code](https://code.haxe.org/category/abstract-types/abstracts-with-type-params.html).

Comment: Not sure if I get the question but don't you just need `Std.instance` instead of your doCast function?

Comment: @szczepanpp I understand what you are saying. For me it's enough to check if variable is `Foo` (underlying type) and then treat it as `Bar` (abstract) - that's the desired behavior of my cast function.

Comment: @szczepanpp what I'm trying to do: we have some gui system, and we have some simple script language and variables that are stored in gui nodes. Values of that variables are just `Dynamic`, and they are set by gui script, so I can make no assumption of their type in my code. What I need to do is to check their type and if it's what I expect - then do something. And since it's a repeating pattern I want to do that in one line without introducing any temporary variables.

Comment: @MarkKnol Yes `Std.instance` does the same as my cast. But it also lacks the possiblities I need. It cannot cast to abstract, it even can`t cast to built-in types like Int or Bool (I know they are also technically abstracts).

Comment: If you really need that much of a flexibility (object of any type can be assigned to any node's value) I'd abstract away value as an enum (e.g. `enum Value{ OfFoo(v: Foo); OfFoo2(v: Foo2); }`) or a simple container type (e.g. `class Value { var type: String; var v: Dynamic; function get<T>(): T return cast v; }` and then `if(value.type == 'Foo') var v: Foo = value.get();`). Since you have to tell the compiler the type you're working with anyway, you can assign object that you know is instance of `Foo` to a `Bar` variable which is an `abstract` (for the compiler).

Comment: @MarkKnol I've just remembered why I was unable to use `Std.instance`: it makes compile-time check for type and thus can't be used with value of type `Any`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually that cannot work at all like that, since `Std.is(value, AbstractType)` will always fail because the abstract does not exist any more at runtime.

See https://try.haxe.org/#1Afb5, and especially:

- Use `@:forward` to access `foo` from `Bar` instances ([forward doc](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-forward.html))
- Use `from Foo` to safe cast `Foo` instances into `Bar` instances (see [implicit cast doc](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-implicit-casts.html)) (note that this feature on itself may be exactly what you were trying to achieve: https://try.haxe.org/#cc903)

Comment: So the only possible way here is macroses... Not sure it's worth it.